# Create an excel formula where ("Monday" - 1) = "Sunday"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Lets say in Column A there are days of the week ("Monday") and in the B Column I want a formula to output the day before ("Sunday"). Does anyone know which formula could make this possible short of creating a nested If function that asks for lists each day of the week?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure that they are only text strings `"Monday"` and not a date formatted `dddd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are just text strings and not a date formatted `dddd` then use this formula:

```
=TEXT(MATCH(A1,{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0),"dddd")
```

[image]

---

Found a shorter formula:

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT((ROW($1:$7))*(TEXT(ROW($2:$8),"dddd")=A1)),"dddd")
```

[image]

Comment: And if it _is_ a date formatted with "dddd", try `=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A1)-1,"dddd")`